# What happens if Kezan Mystic is played after Snipe?

Tags: hearthstone

Can Kezan Mystic steal a played Snipe?
Will Kezan be killed or will it steal the secret first and not be killed?
[image: Kezan Mystic]
[image: Snipe]

Comment: The wiki page for Snipe says "Like all secrets, Snipe takes effect after any Battlecry from the triggering minion". Is there any reason to expect it wouldn't be the same here?

Comment: The order in which effects trigger is first the Battlecry then the secret. No matter what secret it may be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the Kezan Mystic on the [Heartstone Gamepedia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kezan_Mystic) in the notes, you'll see it specifically states:

"Since Battlecries always activate before any summon-related Secrets, Kezan Mystic can steal a Secret such as Snipe and Mirror Entity without triggering it."